# What is the best time for a mom to go back to work after giving birth from the psychological and healthy attachment point of view?

Tags: toddler, development, daycare, psychology, attachment

Given money is not a matter of concern, and the mother cares more about the health and future of her child rather than her career development/future, when is a good time for a mother to go back to work after giving birth?

I have read [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3115616/) article that talks about the attachment theory and I wonder if it is best for the child to be with her mom for at least 2 years?

On the other hand, I hear some parents talk about how their kids learn a lot of useful things at child care and how it is beneficial for kids to spend their time at child care. So, it makes me think that maybe it is in the interest of the child to be taken care of at a child care center rather than be with her mom all the time (before the age of 2 I mean).

I am looking for other articles to understand whether it is best for my baby's mental health to be in childcare or to be with the mother. I am trying to understand what science says about what's best for the mental health of the baby.

Comment: I'm putting this on a temporary hold as unclear what you're asking. You have cited a paper in which the authors of a study of over 2000 families (probably not exactly like yours) conclude that "...even a relatively brief separation within the first 2 years of life can have implications for child well-being three years later." Are you asking for studies that differ in conclusions from that paper, or for personal anecdotes? Personal anecdotes aren't subjected to scientific assessment. Asking for studies is fine. Asking for when it's "best" to return to work is asking for personal opinion.

Comment: Please see [this page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the help center which states that if every answer is equally valid, the question is not a good fit for the SE model. If you can edit your question to ask a specific, primarily non-opinion-based question, please do so and flag for reopening. Thanks!

Comment: @Maryam - Your edit is insufficient to change the nature of anecdote vs. research. Anecdote does not carry the same weight as research in the SE network. The question is basically unchanged.

Comment: Hi Maryam; I've edited your question slightly for wording and to make sure it's on topic.  Can you read it and see if the changes I made are in keeping with what you're hoping for?  The way I read it you're mostly looking for research, so I focused it on that.  If you're mostly looking for personal experience, we'd probably have to write a somewhat different question, but we could do that as well if that's really what you're going after.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your edit. It made my question more clear.